# Plot many variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

Having a dataframe like this one:

From a dataframe like this one:

```
data <- data.frame(year = c(2010,2011,2012,2010,2011,2012), 
                   name = c("stock1","stock1","stock1","stock2","stock2","stock2"), 
                   value = c(0,3,1,4,1,3))
```

I would like to create a plot and I use this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=data, xName="year", groupName="name", brewerPalette="Blues")
```

but I can't receive the plot. Anything wrong in the call?

Comment: Try `ggplot(data=data, aes(x=year, y=value, group=name)) + geom_point()` and consider http://r-statistics.co/ggplot2-Tutorial-With-R.html

Comment: BTW, go back to all your past questions and either(preferred) accept an answer that helped you solve the problem or upvote those other answers that may have helped. It's common courtesy. Acceptance helps close the question and helps future viewers. You get to increase your reputation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year,value,fill=name))+
  geom_col()+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a grouped bar plot (as I guessed from your code), this code may be helpful:

```
 ggplot(data = data, aes(x = as.factor(year), y = value, fill = name)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.8), width = 0.7) +
   scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```